# IOS restkit error

Tags: ios, restkit

I am sending a Post with object loader and getting this error in output window.
FYI, My `didFailWithError:` delegate never got hit. Not sure why.

```
`objectLoader:didFailWithError:]:` unrecognized selector `sent to class 0x123608`
```

How did i find out what is 0x123608?

I set the router in AppDelegate class and Mapping in AppDelegate too.

here is a method in my class which inherit RKObjectLoaderDelegate.
I am using shared singleton.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:review usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){       
//     loader.params=params,
       loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[myclass class]];
       loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; // We want to send this request as JSON
       loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
       loader.serializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping serializationMappingUsingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping* mapping) {
           [mapping mapAttributes:@"field1", @"field2",@"field3",nil];            
       }];
       loader.targetObject = nil;
       loader.delegate = self;
   }];       
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post code snippets and the full error message to get much help here.

Comment: his question doesn't need code snippets. It asks how to find what object it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `self` as your delegate (`loader.delegate = self;`) but it seems that you do not implement the delegate method `objectLoader:didFailWithError:` and/or do not declare that you conform to the delegate protocol `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`.
`– objectLoader:didFailWithError: required method` is a required method to implement in the delegate.

Comment: I did inherit RKObjectLoaderDelegate and ovveride objectLoader:didFailWithError.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the message `didFailWithError:` and your class is not able to recognize it. Did you implemented that method in your class? As for the `didFailWithError:` not being called it's because your didn't implemented or you didn't implemented on the right class.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the RestKit source, in file `RKObjectLoader.m`, you will see the `didFailWithError message` has this code:

```
    if (!self.isCancelled)
    {
        [self informDelegateOfError:error];
    }
```

When I get timeout errors, it gets to this if statement and the `isCancelled` is set to `YES`, so it skips the code to inform the delegate.  This appears to be a bug in the `RestKit` code.  This code is very different from the previous version of `RestKit` that I used.  I do not know exactly why the `isCancelled` `boolean` is set to `YES`, but if you comment out the if statement it will pass the error to the delegate as expected.